# Change Visual Studio 2015 Visualizers and StartPages folder location

Tags: visual-studio

I managed to change the default project folder location on Visual Studio 2015 simply changing the available options.

But I still get both Visualizers and StartPages folder being created in the old folder every time I launch Visual Studio.

If I delete the folder they are automatically created again.

How can I make this folder follow the default location of my projects and settings?

Answer (score 2):

I understand the frustration, as this is something I always like to modify myself.

There is a registry key that you can modify the path in that should handle the StartPages location. That is at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0` (for VS 2015) and it's called `VisualStudioLocation`. You can modify its path to match your custom location in the same way you changed the ones available in the **Options...** dialog.

While you're there, you'll see more path keys whose names begin with "**Default**" that you also might want to modify. I can't be certain which one handles the Visualizers folder, but I have modified them all, and my Visualizers folder now goes to my custom location, along with **StartPages** and everything else.

Comment: I still had to look for some additional keys under "Visual Studio" registry folder and do the same data changes, but at the end of the day it worked great! Thank you!